# Create React App 4 not applying custom eslint configuration during the compiling process

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint, eslintrc

### Context

It used to be that you had to set the `EXTEND_ESLINT` flag to `true` in your `.env` file, and then add this to your `package.json`

```json
// package.json

"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "./.eslintrc.json"
    ]
  },
```

Since CRA4 it is possible to [extend](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config) the base eslint configuration used during the compiling process, without enabling any flag since, apparently, it's [enabled by default](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#eslint)

My `.eslintrc.json` file is this

```json
// .eslintrc.json

{
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "plugin:jest-dom/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["jest-dom", "@emotion", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "no-console": "warn"
  },
  "overrides": [
    // TS only rules
    {
      "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error"
      }
    }
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  }
}
```

and my `package.json` is this

```json
// package.json

"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "./.eslintrc.json"
    ]
  },
```

Running `eslint src --fix-dry-run --ext .tsx,.ts,.js,.jsx` gives me `✖ 30 problems (2 errors, 28 warnings)`

### The problem

It is my understanding that the same errors should show up when CRA compiles the code, since, supposedly, the eslint configuration is extended. However, my project builds just fine, with no warnings at all.

### Things I have tried

```json
// package.json

"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      ".eslintrc.json"
    ]
  },
```

```json
// package.json

"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app", // even though my config already extends that
      "./.eslintrc.json"
    ]
  },
```

```json
// package.json

"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app", // even though my config already extends that
      ".eslintrc.json"
    ]
  },
```

```json
// package.json

"eslintConfig": {
    //move my whole eslint configuration here and remove the .eslintrc.json file
  },
```

*Nothing* seems to actually *extend* the eslint configuration that CRA uses when it compiles.

### The question

Do I do something wrong here, or does this look like an issue with CRA?

Comment: What happens if you run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint src --fix-dry-run --ext .tsx,.ts,.js,.jsx`? Perhaps it's an issue with a different eslint version installed globally?

Comment: Nope, no globally installed eslint (`which eslint` from a terminal shows nothing, to make sure). Running what you suggested gives the exact same output as what I describe in the question.

Comment: Here is a patch to log the options passed to the ESLintPlugin, if you can run a build and include the output of the options that were evaluated that could maybe provide more information: https://gist.github.com/ricmatsui/8eeb353607cb20d39507db983b20ff1c (You can apply the patch manually or with `patch-package` package)

Comment: I replied under the gist with the logs, thanks

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. @DimitrisKaragiannis did you ever find a solution to make the warnings show up in the terminal output for CRA?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `.eslintcache` file in the project folder, try removing it and building again.

It is possible to debug the entire build with `node --inspect-brk node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build` and using chrome://inspect set breakpoints to possibly trace why ESLint is behaving differently, or creating a new project from the template to determine what is causing the behavior to change.

Comment: Ok, this is not exactly helpful, since it's not telling me something new, but since you were the only one who got into the trouble of replying, the bounty is yours. Cheers